# Is there Web Container custom property com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppresserrorpageodrheader="true" equivalent in Open liberty?

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty, server.xml, custom-properties, web-container

In WAS Liberty documentation I can find the Web Container Custom property com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppresserrorpageodrheader (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=configuration-web-container-custom-properties#com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppressErrorPageODRHeader)

What is the equivalent in Open Liberty? How can I set it to true? Where do I set it?

Thanks,
Gilson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest trying to add the following to your server.xml:

```
<webContainer com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppresserrorpageodrheader="true"/>
```

Comment: ok, would it do anything though since that property is not in the Open Liberty documentation (https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.4/reference/config/webContainer.html)

How many <webContainer> elements can I have in the server.xml since there is one on the existent server.xml already?

Comment: Looking through the [Open Liberty source code](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/release/dev/com.ibm.ws.webcontainer/src/com/ibm/wsspi/webcontainer/WCCustomProperties.java), it's in there so it should work.
You can have as many valid webContainer attributes as you'd like.  They can be specified in a single webContainer element, or multiple which will be automatically merged.  Refer to the doc [here](https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.4/reference/config/server-configuration-overview.html#_configuration_merging)